# Давайте перенесём политоту в отдельный чат?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, чат

Политика - довольно грязное дело и даже обсуждение её оставляет некоторый осадок. А ещё политика разъединяет людей и настраивает их друг против друга. Это происходит и в рамках одной страны, и тем более между странами, а у нас есть участники из множества стран.

Я устал от политоты в основном чате. Неприятно заходить туда, где раньше было больше профессиональных тем, и постоянно видеть споры о политике. Кажется, я не один такой. Если вы тоже устали - поддержите моё предложение. :)

**Итак, предлагаю перенести такие обсуждения в специально выделенный чат: [Политота на ru.SO](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47216/ru-so).**

Это предложение вынесено по итогам [обсуждения в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33069356#33069356).

---

> 6 января 2017 то же решение было принято в рамках всей сети Stack Exchange: [If you're gonna talk Politics, you must respect those who disagree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289398/if-youre-gonna-talk-politics-you-must-respect-those-who-disagree)

Comment: `где раньше было больше профессиональных тем,` - я в принципе за множество тем. Не обязательно проф. Даже просто о котиках. Но конкретно политота да - достала. Голосую за президента Nick Volynkin..... А.. это не предвыборная компания ж)

Comment: За то, чтобы убрать обсуждение политики с этого сайта вообще. Теоретически конструктивные дискуссии возможны, но на практике, говоря о политике, люди только показывают, какие они низкоразвитые существа. Спасибо.

Comment: У вас же ромб! Мы вас для чего выбирали, не нужно никого спрашивать, нужно показать этим грязным политиканам где их место! :))) А если серьезно, то боюсь отдельный чат-резервация не поможет, если человек хочет копаться в экскриментах, то это на долго.

Comment: ВООБЩЕ не допускать обсуждения на политические темы. Этой грязи в жизни достаточно. Здесь - не место. Не нужно опускаться до такого уровня.

Answer (score 1):

Против отдельного чата.

За запрет обсуждения политики.

В Сети достаточно ресурсов для того, что бы пообщаться о политике. На данном ресурсе это излишне.

Comment: Довольно странное требование, с учетом того что инфраструктура чатов общая для всех тематических Q&A,  а сайт вопросов и ответов о политике в сети StackExchange присутствует.

Comment: @Nofate комната, однако, приписана именно к ruSO. Будь она приписана к соответствующему сообществу, вопросов бы не было. Хотя нет, были бы, но уже по поводу языка...

Comment: Вы не сможете административными мерами запретить темы для разговора, тут же начнётся обсуждение, что считать, а что не считать политикой. Намного лучше дать людям выпустить пар в отдельном чате. А уж под эгидой какого сайта они там собираются, не всё ли равно?

Comment: *VladD*, противоречите самому себе. Какой смысл в отдельном чате, если, по Вашим словам, неясно, *что считать, а что не считать политикой*? Развернуто: если нельзя разграничить, то "политота" так и останется в основном чате!===*что считать, а что не считать* - в спорных ситуациях решат модераторы, сообщество, и не допустят таких обсуждений вообще.