# Модерация чатов Сети

Tags: поддержка, faq, модерация, чат

На основе каких принципов модерируются чаты Сети?

Answer (score 3):

### Предполагайте добрые намерения

Весь наш сайт — это попытка великодушных деятельных людей сделать жизнь остальных много проще, лучше. Мы делимся знаниями и опытом, которые в ином случае люди бы зачастую нигде и никогда бы не нашли. Делимся безвозмездно. Помните об этом, и всякий раз, когда вам кажется, что кто–то поступает с вами несправедливо. Перед тем как обидеться, уточните, не произошло ли недоразумение. Предполагайте добрые намерения.

### Философия чатов сети Stack Exchange

Типичная повторяющаяся картина:

1. **Удивление от тревог на сообщениях «на грани»**. Внезапно, сообщения, которые были бы удалены на основном сайте, начинают удаляться и в чате. Появляется недопонимание происходящего — «ведь это же чат, а не сайт вопросов и ответов?»
2. **Неоднозначные темы, порождающие драмы, обсуждение личностей и преследования**. Некоторые участники приносят темы, призванные поляризовать сообщество в чаты, которые посвященные совершенно иной теме, зарождая ненависть и нетерпимость в сообществе.
3. **Модераторы *сети* пытаются разрешить первую или вторую проблему**. Те, кого задело скандируют — «Тебя кто–то выбирал модератором этого чата? Покинь чат!», начиная волну возмущений.

Это не случайные проблемы какого–то одного сообщества, это шаблон повторяющийся на на всех сайтах снова и снова. На наш взгляд, проблема кроется не в [языке, как таковом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4020/6), и даже не в отдельных участниках (хотя, следует признать, часто можно встретить очень токсичных людей), а в неверном понимании философии системы и неоправданных ожиданий от других участников. Как результат, хотелось бы отметить, что…

- **Наши чаты не IRC**. Все сообщения по умолчанию публичны и привязаны к учетной записи участника на основном сайте.
- **Наши чаты модерируется участниками**. Рядовые участники, отмечающие сообщения тревогами, проверяющие участники с высокой репутацией и модераторы сети — все принимают участие в решениях о допустимости содержимого.
- **Наши чаты модерируются**. На платформе нет чатов, в которых разрешено все, что угодно. Все комнаты модерируются согласно [Нормам поведения](/conduct).
- **Чаты неотъемлемая часть сайтов вопросов и ответов**. Привилегии участия в чатах вы получаете взаимодействуя на основном сайте, там же можете их и потерять.

Наша система чатов — это отличное дополнение к вопросам и ответам на основном сайте, но не годится для многих других целей, в том числе и тех, которые решают общеизвестные платформы чатов. Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на [краткое руководство по чатам](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq).

Основная статья: «[Toward a philosophy of Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270587/274323)».

### [Нормы поведения](/conduct) действуют в чатах

> #### Никаких резких замечаний или оскорблений
>
> #### Никакой травли
>
> #### Никаких переходов на личности или персональных нападков
>
> #### Никого преследования

Хотя чат место неформальное, [мы просим участников](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) не отходить далеко от основной темы. Злость, гнев за житейским обиды, агрессия, как открытая, так и в пассивном форме не является темой чатов Stack Exchange.

Для поддержания профессиональной доброжелательной атмосферы, мы просим участников оставить все вышеописанное (и аналогичное) за пределами любых наших сайтов.

Если вы считаете, что что–то пошло не так, [задайте вопрос о поведении](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4790). Если у вас не получается, отправьте ваш запрос через [форму обратной связи](/contact) и сотрудники компании или модераторы сообщества вам обязательно ответят.

Дополнительно:

- «[Can we get some official guidelines for chat suspension lengths?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238176/can-we-get-some-official-guidelines-for-chat-suspension-lengths)»

### Модерация чатов сообществом

Следует подчеркнуть и выделить курсивом — ***чаты модерируются сообществом***. На наших сайтах есть широкий спектр привилегий модерации, которые выдаются системой автоматически. Решение по содержимому может быть принято на любом из уровней: обычными участниками (тревогой), участниками с высокой репутацией, модератором или управляющим.

Несколько ключевых фактов о том, как устроена система:

1. Чем выше уровень привилегий модерирования, тем меньше участников требуется для принятия решений. Следствие: модератор или управляющий сообществом принимает решение самостоятельно.
2. Если на одном из уровней модерирования участники не увидели проблемы с содержимом, это не означает, что проблемы нет. Участник с большими привилегиями может переопределить решение, принятое участниками с меньшими привилегиями. Следствие: хотя сотрудники компании, в обычном случае, не вмешиваются в модерацию, последнее слово остается за ними.
3. В пределе любой участник может получить наивысшие привилегии в системе, в том числе стать избранным модератором (или даже [откликнуться на открытую вакансию компании](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here)).

Статьи на тему:

- «[Set a benchmark on acceptable behaviour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284569/set-a-benchmark-on-acceptable-behaviour)»
- «[A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat)»

Comment: Вот эту страницу хорошо бы перевести https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: В контексте этих правил политоты у нас вообще не должно быть тогда, в принципе (: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3954/15479

Comment: *Предполагайте добрые намерения* — не хватает приписки, что отдельные модераторы этому правилу редко следуют. В результате, хотя и следует предполагать добрые намерения от окружающих, всегда надо исходить из того, что модератор их от вас предполагать не будет. Даже в тексте вот упомянуты "пассивная агрессия" и "токсичные темы" — сущности субъективные.

Comment: @Athari Если вы когда-либо увидите что–либо подобное на наших сайтах, пожалуйста, напишите мне напрямую или через форму обратной связи. Обязательно все разрешим.

Comment: Разрешили. Срок действия блокировки истечёт 14 сен '19.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, травля, переходы на личности и преследования можно трактовать как душе угодно. Это слишком общие термины, за которыми ничего не стоит. К примеру, в хорошо известной Вам ситуации были использованы первые 2 повода, тогда как с точки зрения всего остального чата (и я подчёркиваю это) ничего подобного не наблюдалось. Мы не можем не переходить на личности, т.к. мы общаемся с личностью. Не должно быть оскорблений, а правило «не переходить на личности» это просто набор слов, как 282 статья в УК РФ. Поэтому предлагаю убрать все общие фразы, заменив их конкретикой.

Comment: @ixSci «*можно трактовать как душе угодно.*» — Представьте, что у нас есть дорога без разметки. Правила говорят, что надо ездить по правой стороне дроги. Цитированное утверждение эквивалентно вопросу «где заканчивается правая сторона и начинается левая?» В принципе, этот вопрос никого не интересует до тех пор пока машины могут разъехаться, а трения появляются лишь в случае, когда кто–то пошел на рискованный обгон и зацепил встречку.

Comment: Для дороги у нас есть метрическая система и мы можем линейкой измерить расстояние (хотя для случаев, например, обоюдного выезда на встречку этого становится недостаточно!) Наш случай еще сложнее: мы измеряем взаимодействие по шкале уважения, а эта шкала у каждого своя. Чтобы как–то разрешить этот спорный момент, сообщество делегировало выбор избранным модераторам. Пожалуйста, посмотрите мой ответ в вопросе «[Оскорбление или нет, вот в чём вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7842/6)».

Comment: Травля и переходы на личности — это то, что совершенно недопустимо на наши сайтах. Это явно указано в [Нормах](/conduct), например: «*Если у вас появились любые сомнения о допустимости высказывания, не пишите его.*» Если вы видите проблему в чьем–либо поведении, на мой взгляд, следует закрыть чат и [задать вопрос на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4790/6).